# How can i retrieve the userID in the front-end made using React.js

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, sql-server

I'm finishing my Full Stack Web app (with JWT token authentication based on roles), but im struggling with the front-end. I need to know what is the best practice for obtaining the UserID in the front-end so i can make fetches like "GetObservationsByUserID". Notice that the backend is fully functional.

```
 const fetchObservations = async (userID) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/api/GetObservationsByUserID/${userID}`, {
        method: 'GET',
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        const responseData = await response.json();
        if (Array.isArray(responseData.data)) {
          setObservations(responseData.data);
        } else {
          console.error('Observations data is not in the expected format:', responseData);
        }
      } else {
        console.error('Failed to fetch observations:', response.statusText);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('An error occurred while fetching observations:', error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: I suppose that userId is extractable from the JWT? There are libraries to help you decode the JWT token. The best practice in this case would be to decode that userId from the JWT token and pass it inside this function. To add to your question about best practices, all functions in React.js should be passed into `useCallback` function as a parameter. Read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usecallback.asp

Comment: Depending on the implementation of the JWT, there are different librairies used to get back the userId from it indeed. It's in the authentication information anyway.
Another thing to be careful about, don't put your userId in the URL of the method.
But if your API is secured, a token could be fetched for the Back-end as well (if these are two differents apps, otherwise the same token) so the back-end can access the userId from the authentication info as well.
It's not ideal to put the userId in clear in an URL.

Answer (score 0):

in my job we are using the Jason Tailor template for Clean Architecture.
https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture

And to retrive the current user ( the user that is logged), you can use the https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture/tree/main/src/Application/Common/Interfaces/ICurrentUserService.cs

So, if you need to get some information about the logged user, instead of try to pass from your front end, you could use directly from your back-end, as a dependency injection.

I not sure if I understand de purpose to retrieve the userId on frontend, if I don't please tell me

Comment: First of all, thank you for the suggestion. I just wanted to make a fetch using a request from the backend that uses the userID to retrieve a list of observation from that specific user

Comment: You want to get the userId of all users?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `react-router-dom`. It'd suggest useParams()

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function YourComponent {
  let { userID } = useParams();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using c# as a backend and i suppose u can modify it. and in the JWT there is UserID given or anything that can identity the user, u can get that in the backend directly without passing the user ID

```
using System.Security.Claims;
[HttpPost("addorganization")]
[Authorize(Roles ="Admin")]
    public IActionResult AddOrganization([FromBody] Organization org)
    {
        try
        {
            string Email = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
            string Result = _services.AddOrganization(org, Email);
            return Ok(Result);
        }
        catch
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

here the like `User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email)` will get u the Email embedded that u can used to fetch the ID later or there are multiple options in claims including ID `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier`